# Old sci-fi show: Scientist sent unusual electronic components in mail which turn out to come from aliens

Tags: story-identification

I saw this show in France in the late 70s. I believe it was in black an white so it may have originated in the 60s. As far as I recall this was a short story.

It had the same feeling as the Twilight Zone and it could possibly be a part of it.

The story takes place with scientists in some kind of research lab that looked contemporary for the time.
The leading character, a scientist, start to receive in his mail some electronic components he hasn't ordered and when he decides to test what they are, he seems very surprised that they don't have the same characteristics as anything he knows.
In one scene he demonstrates to one of his colleagues how it takes a lot to blow one of them compared to the ones they normally have.

The backstory is some aliens sending him parts to build equipment that will allow communication.

Comment: I watched it on a TV; I believe it was Saturday or Sunday afternoon programming.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Almost certainly [*This Island Earth*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_Island_Earth) (1955)

> Dr. Cal Meacham is flying to his laboratory in a borrowed Lockheed T-33 Shooting Star jet. Just before landing, the jet's engine fails, but he is saved from crashing by a mysterious green glow.
>
> At the lab is an unusual substitute for the electronic condensers that he had ordered. Instead, he discovers instructions and parts to build a complex device called an "interocitor". Neither Meacham nor his assistant Joe Wilson have heard of such a device, but they immediately begin its construction. When they finish, a mysterious man named Exeter appears on the interocitor screen and informs Meacham that he has passed the test. His ability to build the interocitor demonstrates that he is gifted enough to be part of Exeter's special research project.

---

> In one scene he demonstrates to one of his colleagues how it takes a lot to blow one of them compared to the ones they normally have.

[image: GIF showing the characters using an electronic piece of equipment, watching as a red bulb gets brighter and brighter until the screen goes white]

Comment: Movie based on a novel by Raymond F. Jones. But the movie wasn't black and white, was it?

Comment: this is it! I thought it was aliens communicating. Another thing my memory may have failed at is that possibly the TV set was a black and white one :) thanks a lot, I'll watch it again

Comment: As it turns out they **are** aliens.